# Jfrog xray is not detecting CVE-2022-21724 for postgresql jar

Tags: jfrog-xray

Jfrog xray is not detecting CVE-2022-21724 for postgresql jar , In our application we are using postgresql-42.2.18.jar above CVE is not detecting.

Thanks and Regards,
S Sathish
9840809251

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed the same artifact in Artifactory and scanned it with Xray. I was able to see the mentioned CVE in it. Kindly make sure that Xray database sync is up to date. After that, select the artifact and click on "Scan for violations" in the Actions tab and share the screenshot here.
[image]

Comment: Hi Team, 

While taking postgresql-42.2.18.jar from below Source path of Official Postgresql , Jfrog xray able to detect the vulnerability. jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

we are performing jar signer for security purpose for all jar , As of now found postgresql-42.2.18.jar is not detecting the security vulnerability on Jfrog Xray. While other signed jar like Apache XMRPC, Jackson-databind vulnerability are detected in Jfrog Xray.

Can you please explain the technical reason on why JFrogxray is not detecting the vulnerability in the jar is signed internally?